# How to match either or group in Regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex.

```
([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)\s?(?:-|TO)\s?([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)
```

which works for to capture from and to time.

```
8-8:30AM MON TUES THURS FRI
NO PARKING (SANITATION BROOM SYMBOL) 7AM-7:30AM EXCEPT SUNDAY
```

However, I want it to be able to capture either the number or the word `MIDNIGHT`

```
NO PARKING (SANITATION BROOM SYMBOL) MOON & STARS (SYMBOLS) TUESDAY FRIDAY MIDNIGHT-3AM
```

How do I extend that. This is what I've got so far.

https://regex101.com/r/fC0lI5/7

Here's what my input is

```
NO PARKING (SANITATION BROOM SYMBOL) MOON & STARS (SYMBOLS) TUESDAY FRIDAY MIDNIGHT-3AM
```

I expect the first group to be `MIDNIGHT` and second would be `3AM`

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/xE5oX4/1)?

Comment: It would be better if you provided the code you are using to test the regex and exact expected output. See another similar regex to the above [here](https://regex101.com/r/xD9eX2/1).

Comment: I'll update my question.

Comment: So, my second one looks to be the solution.

Comment: So what was hard about adding midnight to each of the groups? `([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?|MIDNIGHT)\s?(?:-|TO)\s?([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?|MIDNIGHT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(MIDNIGHT|[01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)\s*(?:-|TO)\s*(MIDNIGHT|[01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD9eX2/1)

I just moved the `MIDNIGHT` into the first and second capturing groups as an alternative, and replaced `?` with `*` quantifiers on both sides of `TO` or the hyphen (just in case there can be more than one space there).

Comment: regex101 nice site.....I have been doing this in a linux shell with a color option using egrep....now i am a regex101 fan

Comment: Just note that to use the regex in Python, you need to use a raw string literal `r"<REGEX_HERE>"`. And use `re.finditer` to get all matches, this method is the most convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've already posted, it seems like you just need to put MIDNIGHT in a group. Then you probably want to enclose the two possibilities in a group as well. Like this:

```
(([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)|(MIDNIGHT))?\s?(?:-|TO)\s?([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)
```